# Warning "Overriding address(es) 'http://+:80'." when running in Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

In my Asp.Net Core application I need to support RESTfull api and Grpc together (without TLS) so I have the following configuration in `appsettings.json`

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://+:4998"
    },
    "Grpc": {
      "Url": "http://+:4999",
      "Protocols": "Http2"
    }
  }
}
```

When I start the app in VS I get this warning:

> Overriding address(es) 'http://localhost:4999'. Binding to endpoints
> defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.

The problem is double url configuration. First one by `"applicationUrl"` in `launchSettings.json` and then by `Kestrel` section in the `appsettings.json` file.
To solve this I have added `"externalUrlConfiguration": true` to the `launchSettings.json` file as suggested by this [answer](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4145#issuecomment-439532247).

Now, I'm starting the app in Docker container with the following configuration in Dockerfile

```
ENV DOTNET_Kestrel__Endpoints__Http__Url=http://+:80
ENV DOTNET_Kestrel__Endpoints__Grpc__Url=http://+:8080
ENV DOTNET_Kestrel__Endpoints__Grpc__Protocols=Http2
```

And get this warning again

> Overriding address(es) 'http://+:80'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.

And this time because base Asp.Net Core image configures `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80` environment variable, then I override it with my `Kestrel__Endpoints`.

Is there any way to avoid this warning?

Comment: Does just resetting it using `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=""`  help?

Comment: @Rhumborl, I don't know why my comment was deleted twice, but your solution works. Add it as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does just resetting it using ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="" help? –
Rhumborl
May 26 at 13:11